# PowerShell for loop not adding last value from previously looped arrays

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, for-loop, cdata

I am totally stumped. I am reading data from an XML file into two separate arrays, which is then grouped together in a third array by indices (i.e. `($array-element[0], $array2-element[0])`):

This is what my XML kinda looks like:

**XML**

```
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR1"><![CDATA[123456ABCDEF]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR2"><![CDATA[0.0.0.0]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR3"><![CDATA[Hello World]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR4"><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></COLUMN>
        <COLUMN NAME="ATTR5"><![CDATA[This is some text]]></COLUMN>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

This is my PowerShell script that reads `ATTR2` and `ATTR3` into two separate arrays:

**PowerShell (first two arrays)**

```
$array = @()
$array2 = @()

foreach ($name in $xmldata.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}.'#cdata-section')
{
    $array += $name
}

foreach ($version in $xmldata.RESULTS.ROW.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR2"}.'#cdata-section')
{
    $array2 += $version
}
```

It returns the desired result.

Then I group the matching indices from each array into a new array (`$array3`):

**PowerShell (third array)**

```
$array3 = @()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++)
{
    $array3 += $array[$i] + ", " + $array2[$i]
    $i++
}
```

It returns the desired result (see below):

**Result**

```
Hello World, 0.0.0.0
(so on and so forth...)
```

However, the last `for-loop` refuses to add the last values from `$array` and `$array2` into `$array3`.

`$array.Length` tells me the length of `$array` and `$array2` are 896 *even though* there are only 895 elements. When I return `$array[896]` I get zero results. When I return `$array[895]` it returns the last value I am looking for.

And if the length of the array is indeed 896, then `$i` should stop at 895, correct? So, I assume it would be grabbing the final value (indexed at 895). So, why is my `for-loop` not adding the final value?

Comment: Remove `$i++` from inside the loop body - it's already being done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem with your `for` loop is that you've already specified that `$i++` should be executed after each iteration in the loop signature (`$i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++`), but then you manually call `$i++` inside the body as well.

That being said, the real solution is to *not split the columns into 2 arrays* in the first place. Instead, create a new object for each `ROW` node in the XML when you first iterate over it:

```sh
# assign all output from `foreach` loop to `$array`
$array = foreach($row in $xmldata.RESULTS.ROW){
  # create new object with the pertinent details as property values
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = $row.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR3"}.'#cdata-section'
    Version = $row.COLUMN.Where{ $_.NAME -eq "ATTR2"}.'#cdata-section'
  }
}
```

Now, `$array` will contain one object per `ROW` node, each with their own `Name` and `Version` property